# How can solve Right join in under code

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT T.ID, COUNT(W.ID) AS COUNT1 
FROM WORKORDERS W
WHERE W.HCWORKORDERSTAT_ID IN(
SELECT ID FROM HCWORKORDERSTAT H WHERE CODE NOT IN('CL','CANCEL'))
RIGHT JOIN TRADE 
    ON W.TRADE_ID=TRADE.ID
    GROUP BY T.ID;
```

because error code?

Comment: It's not clear what question you're asking. When you run the code you included, what error do you get?

Comment: your question is Unclear :/

Answer (score 0):

In the ANSI 92 syntax the WHERE clause follows JOIN clause(s). So perhaps this will fix your error:

```
SELECT T.ID, COUNT(W.ID) AS COUNT1 
FROM WORKORDERS W
RIGHT JOIN TRADE 
    ON W.TRADE_ID=TRADE.ID
WHERE W.HCWORKORDERSTAT_ID IN(
     SELECT ID FROM HCWORKORDERSTAT H 
      WHERE CODE NOT IN('CL','CANCEL'))    
GROUP BY T.ID;
```